# Does Superman have a lisp?

Tags: dc, superman

I'm wondering if there is a canonical reference for this [comment](http://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2012/09/why-i-refuse-to-vote-for-barack-obama/262861/#comment-663979618) I found on the internet (not the part about hiding his identity, the part about him having a lisp):

> The reason why Superman hides his identity is because he speaks with a
>   lisp (little known trivia)

Comment: Disclaimer: that link is to a politics-related article, and it's very possible that I've fallen for a snarky troll... but I find the idea of Superman with a speech impediment fascinating.

Comment: Hard to cover a lisp.  You don't usually shift in and out of one on command.

Comment: Many people appear to have a lisp when speaking through radio or television.  Superman being old enough, there are bound to be at least some low quality television recordings where he has a lisp.

Comment: Thhhhhhuperman!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is no canonical evidence for Superman having, or for that matter, EVER having a speech impediment.**

- The Clark Kent identity used by Superman is known for using physical misdirection to appear less imposing and unable to be easily mistaken for Superman. He does this by slumping his shoulders, using a less effective speaking voice, and appearing less confident and in some cases outright clumsy.

[image: What a difference some posture and glasses make...]

*What a difference some posture, glasses, haircut and tone of voice could make.*

- No known iterations of the Man of Steel have ever used a lisp as part of that secret ID. I would not attribute that to anything other than a supposition (unless the writer is a member of DC Comics).

Comment: Is the illustration canonical (e.g. developed by or for comic artists in the franchise), or a fan drawing?

Comment: DC published a similar image some decades ago, trying to rationalize how no one could see through the weak disguise of Clark Kent. I have been looking through my collection for the original set of images, and found this done by a professional artist online. Do not recognize the work but it mirrored DC's original explanation perfectly. I found this art on TV Tropes. I will keep hunting for the original images as well.

Comment: @Thaddeus That looks like Frank Quitely's sketch from the Absolute edition of All Star Superman